# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND In Material

Tags: angularjs

Hi i am trying this "https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.switch" in angular while implementing I am finding some errors in console

```
 file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/css/angular-material.min.css Failed to load resource:          
  net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
  angular.js:9778 TypeError: Cannot read property 'required' of undefined
at link (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular-aria.min.js:9:268)
at nodeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:6579:13)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:5982:15)
at nodeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:6573:24)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:5986:15)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:5989:13)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:5989:13)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:5989:13)
at publicLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:5891:30)



at file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:1384:27 <md-switch ng-model="data.cb1" aria-
  label="Switch 1" class="ng-pristine" tabindex="0">
  angular.js:9778 TypeError: undefined is not a function
at file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular-material.min.js:7:18361
at file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular-material.min.js:8:7953
at nodeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:6579:13)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:5982:15)
at nodeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:6573:24)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:5986:15)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:5989:13)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:5989:13)
at compositeLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:5989:13)
at publicLinkFn (file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/CASjan5/js/angular.js:5891:30) <md-switch ng-
 model="data.cb1" aria-label="Switch 1" class="ng-pristine md-default-theme" tabindex="0">
```

Can some one help me in this issue.

Comment: Have you included the file?  You can use the CDN `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.6.1/angular-material.min.css` or use Bower as described [here](https://github.com/angular/bower-material).  Google often doesn't describe the extra files you need to run one of their examples.

Comment: @Beartums I actually tried CDN only first then i find lots off issues so i saved in my machine and run the file

Comment: I pretty much guessed you did, but there doesn't seem to be any other reason -- it's not saying that the file can't load, but that it wasn't found.  Is there a problem with the path?